# How to make django-photologue autorotate image with info from EXIF?

Tags: django, autorotate, photologue

I need to change orientation of image according to info in EXIF on upload.
Is there any "standard" way for this?
Im trying to patch models now, but not sure its right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did it like this file photologue/models.py:

```
IMAGE_EXIF_ORIENTATION_MAP = {
    6: 0,
    3: 2,
    8: 3,
    1: 4,
}   


    def pre_cache(self):
        if self.EXIF.get('Orientation', 1) is not None:
            im = Image.open(self.image.path)
            im = im.transpose(IMAGE_EXIF_ORIENTATION_MAP[self.EXIF.get('Orientation', 1)])
            im.save(self.image.path)

        cache = PhotoSizeCache()
        for photosize in cache.sizes.values():
            if photosize.pre_cache:
                self.create_size(photosize)
```